# Static string variable not changing when accessed other java activity

Tags: java, android, mysql, exception, connection

I have developed a app in which we can change ip address to connect to database running on xampp server..

This is my MainActivity.java

In which I declared a public static string variable called "ip" and set a default value for it. I changed this ip using menu option using alert box. and when displayed the changed ip using snackbar it shows changes. But trying to access that "ip" in another activity called "doctor_login.java" by Mainactivity.ip. It does not takes changed ip instead it takes default ip itself. Below I have shown screenshots and code. Please help me in this issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { public static String ip="192.168.43.97";// This is default ip
public static final String dbuser = "root";
public static final String dbpass = "kughan";

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "App by KUGHAN EV", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

   if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        AlertDialog.Builder ipalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        ipalert.setCancelable(false);
        ipalert.setTitle("Change IP");
        ipalert.setMessage("Enter your server ip below:");

        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        ipalert.setView(input);
        ipalert.setPositiveButton("CHANGE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                 String cip=input.getText().toString();
                    ip=cip;  // Trying to change ip address from edittext
                    Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(),"Ip changed to "+ip,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(null,null).show();
            }
        });
        ipalert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",null);
        ipalert.show();
    }
    if(id== R.id.showip){
        Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(),"Your IP is "+ip,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(null,null).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                doctor_login tab1 = new doctor_login();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                patient_login tab2 = new patient_login();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "DOCTOR";
            case 1:
                return "PATIENT";
            }
        return null;
    }


}


//This is my doctor_login activity


public class doctor_login extends Fragment {
public static String logged;
public static String loggedid;
private String url;
private static final String user = MainActivity.dbuser;
private static final String pass = MainActivity.dbpass;

EditText usertxt,passtxt;
Button login,reg;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_doctor_login, container, false);
    url ="jdbc:mysql://"+MainActivity.ip+":3306/mediapp";  //getting value from mainactivity ip value 

    usertxt=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    passtxt=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    login=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    reg=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(usertxt.getText().toString().length()==0 || passtxt.getText().toString().length()==0){
                Snackbar.make(getView(),"Fill all credential details",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action",null).show();
            }else{
                testDB();
            }
        }
    });

    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(doctor_login.this.getActivity(),doctor_signup.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Snackbar.make(getView(),"Welcome to DigiMedApp",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action",null).show();
}

public void testDB(){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs =  st.executeQuery("select name,id from doctorlogin where username='"+usertxt.getText().toString()+"' and password='"+passtxt.getText().toString()+"';");
            if(rs.next()){
                logged=rs.getString(1);
                loggedid=rs.getString(2);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Welcome "+rs.getString(1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(doctor_login.this.getActivity(),doctor_home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else
            {
                Snackbar.make(getView(),"Wrong Username or password",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action",null).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

}

Changing the ip using alertdialog
[See the editetxt__Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zURI.png)

When trying to login from doctor_login page it shows connection exception as you can see the ip on which it is trying to connect even after changing the ip

[Exeption__Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rc3A.png)

Comment: Try to store on Shared Preferences instead of static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_doctor_login, container, false);
    url ="jdbc:mysql://"+MainActivity.ip+":3306/mediapp";  //getting value from mainactivity ip value
```

The `doctor_login` fragment is created before the ip change in `MainActivity`.
This valuation is so not at the convenient place as `url` will use the `MainActivity.ip` value present during its initialization and will not take into consideration ip change performed by the user in `MainActivity`.

To solve your problem, generate the url with the IP in the `testDB()` method.

Replace

```
public void testDB(){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

by

```
public void testDB(){
     url ="jdbc:mysql://"+MainActivity.ip+":3306/mediapp";  
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```